# Error: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key projectToolBar?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Hey I can't figure out an error I got. I had my App working and then I'm not sure what I did but it won't open now and instead I get this error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason:     '[<TaskViewController 0x16c9b0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value  coding-compliant for the key projectToolBar.'
```

Any Ideas what might be the problem? I can add my project code if I need to...

### edit:

So i looked and in the interface builder/storyboard there was a link to projectToolBar that didn't have a corresponding line in the header file. I deleted the problem in IB, however, now I am getting a new error and it still isn't working.

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<TaskViewController 0x132dd0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key projectView.'
```

Here is my taskviewController class:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "newTaskWindow.h"

@interface TaskViewController : UIViewController <DismissPopoverDelegate>{

IBOutlet UIScrollView *taskScrollView;
AppDelegate * _appDelegate;
UIDeviceOrientation orientation;
IBOutlet UIView *newTaskView;
IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *newTaskButton;
IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *newTeamMemberButton;
IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *newProjectButton;
IBOutlet UIView*taskView;
IBOutlet UIToolbar *taskToolBar;
NSMutableArray *teamMembers;
NSMutableArray *projects;
NSMutableArray *tasks;
//UIPopoverController *taskPop;

int countForX;
int countForY;
int xOffSet;
int yOffset;
int xMult;
int yMult;
int viewContentSize;
int countForTaskView;
int maxCountForX;
int maxCountForY;
int incrementForYOffset;
int viewContentSizeBase;


}

- (IBAction)newTask:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)newTeamMember:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)newProject:(id)sender;
-(void)setTasksInScreen;


@property(nonatomic, retain) AppDelegate * appDelegate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIPopoverController *myPopover;
@end
@protocol NewsVcDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)FirstViewController:(TaskViewController*)controller didSelectObject:(id)object;

@end
```

//  FirstViewController.m

```
#import "TaskViewController.h"
#import "newTaskWindow.h"
#import "TeamMember.h"
#import "Project.h"
#import "newTeamMemberWindow.h"
#import "newProjectWindow.h"

@implementation TaskViewController
@synthesize myPopover;
@synthesize appDelegate;

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
NSLog(@"Made it to TaskViewController");

self.appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self selector: @selector(deviceOrientationDidChange:) name: UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object: nil];

[self setTasksInScreen];

[super viewDidLoad];

// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

}


//create new Team member in popover myPopover
-(IBAction)newTeamMember:(id)sender{

if ([self.myPopover isPopoverVisible]) {
    //using the setters and getters "goes thru the proper channels" when accessing    objects
    [self.myPopover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
} else {

 newTeamMemberWindow *teamMemberWindow = [[newTeamMemberWindow alloc]init];
    [teamMemberWindow setDelegate:self];
UIPopoverController *teamMemberPop = [[UIPopoverController alloc]initWithContentViewController:teamMemberWindow];


[teamMemberPop setDelegate:self];



[teamMemberPop setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(300, 450)];
//NSLog(@"Got to 6");
self.myPopover = teamMemberPop;
[self.myPopover presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:newTeamMemberButton permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
}

}

//Create new Project in popover myPopover
-(IBAction)newProject:(id)sender{

if ([self.myPopover isPopoverVisible]) {
    //using the setters and getters "goes thru the proper channels" when accessing    objects
    [self.myPopover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
 } else {

newProjectWindow *projectWindow = [[newProjectWindow alloc]init];
    [projectWindow setDelegate:self];
UIPopoverController *projectPop = [[UIPopoverController  alloc]initWithContentViewController:projectWindow];


[projectPop setDelegate:self];


[projectPop setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(300, 450)];

self.myPopover = projectPop;
[self.myPopover presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:newProjectButton permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
}

}



//Create new Task in popover myPopover
-(IBAction)newTask:(id)sender{

if ([self.myPopover isPopoverVisible]) 
{

[self.myPopover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];

} else {



NSString* test1 = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"Robby"];
[teamMembers addObject:test1];
newTaskWindow *newTaskWin = [[newTaskWindow alloc]init];
[newTaskWin setDelegate:self];
UIView *test = [[UIView alloc]init];
[newTaskWin setTeamMembers:teamMembers];
test = newTaskWin.view;

UIPopoverController *taskPop = [[UIPopoverController   alloc]initWithContentViewController:newTaskWin];


[taskPop setDelegate:self];


[taskPop setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(300, 450)];

self.myPopover = taskPop;
[self.myPopover presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:newTaskButton permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];

}

}

-(void)setTasksInScreen{


//remove all views that were in The task view. If you don't do this, a new view is placed on top everytime you call setTasksInScreen method and the buttons begin to overlap. 

for (UIView *view in [taskView subviews]) {
    [view removeFromSuperview];
}

//The placement of the buttons is different depending on which orientation we are in. We handle this with an if statement

if((self.interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) ||   (self.interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)){

    countForX = 0;
    countForY = 0;
    xOffSet = 27;
    yOffset = 60;
    maxCountForX = 3;
    maxCountForY = 4; 
    incrementForYOffset = 911;
    xMult = 250;
    yMult = 210;
    viewContentSize = 0;
    countForTaskView = 1;
    viewContentSizeBase = 911;
    NSLog(@"Portrait view");

}
else{
    countForX = 0;
    countForY = 0;
    maxCountForX = 4;
    maxCountForY = 3; 
    incrementForYOffset = 654;
    xOffSet = 41;
    yOffset = 50;
    xMult = 240;
    yMult = 200;
    viewContentSize = 0;
    countForTaskView = 1;
    viewContentSizeBase = 654;
    NSLog(@"LandScape view");
}

//Create Scrollview to be able to scroll through the different tasks
taskScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height -45)];

    tasks = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:self.appDelegate.tasks];



   Task *tempTask = [[Task alloc]init];
   for(int i =0; i < [tasks count]; i++){
    tempTask = [tasks objectAtIndex:i];
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    //Set the style that you want the date to be here (ie. MM-DD-YYYY ect)
    [formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterFullStyle];
    NSDate *endDateForButton = [tempTask endDate];


    //Use custom Button so that you can add in background pic


    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];


    button.frame = CGRectMake(xOffSet+(countForX*xMult), yOffset +(countForY*yMult), 215, 156);
    UIImage *buttonBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"rectangleImage.png"];
    [button setBackgroundImage:buttonBackground forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    //add labels to button for information
    UILabel *taskName = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 200, 45)];
    taskName.text = [tempTask taskName];
    [taskName setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
    [button addSubview:taskName];

    //Label that says "Due on"

    UILabel *dueLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 50, 200, 45)];
    dueLabel.text = @"Due on";
    [dueLabel setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
    [button addSubview:dueLabel];


    UILabel *endDate = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 80, 200, 45)];
    endDate.text = [formatter stringFromDate:[tempTask endDate]];
    [endDate setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
    [button addSubview:endDate];



    countForX++;

    if(countForX >= maxCountForX)
    {

        countForY++;
        countForX = 0;

    }

    if(countForY >=maxCountForY)
    {

        countForY = 0;
        countForX = 0;
        yOffset +=incrementForYOffset; 
        countForTaskView++;

    }

     [taskScrollView addSubview:button];


}//for loop

[taskView addSubview:taskScrollView];
[taskView bringSubviewToFront:taskToolBar];

//[taskScrollView addSubview:viewForTaskScrollView];

viewContentSize = viewContentSizeBase * (countForTaskView);
taskScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(taskView.frame.size.width, viewContentSize);
[taskScrollView setPagingEnabled:YES];
}

-(void)setProjectsInScreen{


//remove all views that were in The task view. If you don't do this, a new view is    placed on top everytime you call setTasksInScreen method and the buttons begin to overlap. 

for (UIView *view in [taskView subviews]) {
    [view removeFromSuperview];
}

//The placement of the buttons is different depending on which orientation we are in. We  handle this with an if statement

if((self.interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) ||  (self.interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)){

    countForX = 0;
    countForY = 0;
    xOffSet = 27;
    yOffset = 60;
    maxCountForX = 3;
    maxCountForY = 4; 
    incrementForYOffset = 911;
    xMult = 250;
    yMult = 210;
    viewContentSize = 0;
    countForTaskView = 1;
    viewContentSizeBase = 911;
    NSLog(@"Portrait view");

}
else{
    countForX = 0;
    countForY = 0;
    maxCountForX = 4;
    maxCountForY = 3; 
    incrementForYOffset = 654;
    xOffSet = 41;
    yOffset = 50;
    xMult = 240;
    yMult = 200;
    viewContentSize = 0;
    countForTaskView = 1;
    viewContentSizeBase = 654;
    NSLog(@"LandScape view");
}

//Create Scrollview to be able to scroll through the different tasks
taskScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height -45)];



projects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:self.appDelegate.projects];



Project *tempProject = [[Project alloc]init];
for(int i =0; i < [tasks count]; i++){
    tempProject = [tasks objectAtIndex:i];
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];


    button.frame = CGRectMake(xOffSet+(countForX*xMult), yOffset +(countForY*yMult), 215, 156);
    UIImage *buttonBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"rectangleImage.png"];
    [button setBackgroundImage:buttonBackground forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    //add labels to button for information
    UILabel *projectName = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 200, 45)];
    projectName.text = [tempProject projectName];
    [projectName setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
    [button addSubview:projectName];

    //Label that says "Due on"

    UILabel *dueLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 50, 200, 45)];
    dueLabel.text = @"Due on";
    [dueLabel setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
    [button addSubview:dueLabel];




    countForX++;

    if(countForX >= maxCountForX)
    {

        countForY++;
        countForX = 0;

    }

    if(countForY >=maxCountForY)
    {

        countForY = 0;
        countForX = 0;
        yOffset +=incrementForYOffset; 
        countForTaskView++;

    }

    [taskScrollView addSubview:button];


}//for loop

[taskView addSubview:taskScrollView];
[taskView bringSubviewToFront:taskToolBar];

//[taskScrollView addSubview:viewForTaskScrollView];

viewContentSize = viewContentSizeBase * (countForTaskView);
taskScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(taskView.frame.size.width, viewContentSize);
[taskScrollView setPagingEnabled:YES];
}

-(void)setTeamMembersInScreen{


//remove all views that were in The task view. If you don't do this, a new view is placed on top everytime you call setTasksInScreen method and the buttons begin to overlap. 

for (UIView *view in [taskView subviews]) {
    [view removeFromSuperview];
}

//The placement of the buttons is different depending on which orientation we are in. We handle this with an if statement

if((self.interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) || (self.interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)){

    countForX = 0;
    countForY = 0;
    xOffSet = 27;
    yOffset = 60;
    maxCountForX = 3;
    maxCountForY = 4; 
    incrementForYOffset = 911;
    xMult = 250;
    yMult = 210;
    viewContentSize = 0;
    countForTaskView = 1;
    viewContentSizeBase = 911;
    NSLog(@"Portrait view");

}
else{
    countForX = 0;
    countForY = 0;
    maxCountForX = 4;
    maxCountForY = 3; 
    incrementForYOffset = 654;
    xOffSet = 41;
    yOffset = 50;
    xMult = 240;
    yMult = 200;
    viewContentSize = 0;
    countForTaskView = 1;
    viewContentSizeBase = 654;
    NSLog(@"LandScape view");
}

//Create Scrollview to be able to scroll through the different tasks
taskScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height -45)];

tasks = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:self.appDelegate.tasks];



Task *tempTask = [[Task alloc]init];
for(int i =0; i < [tasks count]; i++){
    tempTask = [tasks objectAtIndex:i];
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    //Set the style that you want the date to be here (ie. MM-DD-YYYY ect)
    [formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterFullStyle];
    NSDate *endDateForButton = [tempTask endDate];


    //Use custom Button so that you can add in background pic


    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];


    button.frame = CGRectMake(xOffSet+(countForX*xMult), yOffset +(countForY*yMult), 215, 156);
    UIImage *buttonBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"rectangleImage.png"];
    [button setBackgroundImage:buttonBackground forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    //add labels to button for information
    UILabel *taskName = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 200, 45)];
    taskName.text = [tempTask taskName];
    [taskName setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
    [button addSubview:taskName];

    //Label that says "Due on"

    UILabel *dueLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 50, 200, 45)];
    dueLabel.text = @"Due on";
    [dueLabel setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
    [button addSubview:dueLabel];


    UILabel *endDate = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 80, 200, 45)];
    endDate.text = [formatter stringFromDate:[tempTask endDate]];
    [endDate setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
    [button addSubview:endDate];



    countForX++;

    if(countForX >= maxCountForX)
    {

        countForY++;
        countForX = 0;

    }

    if(countForY >=maxCountForY)
    {

        countForY = 0;
        countForX = 0;
        yOffset +=incrementForYOffset; 
        countForTaskView++;

    }

    [taskScrollView addSubview:button];


}//for loop

[taskView addSubview:taskScrollView];
[taskView bringSubviewToFront:taskToolBar];

//[taskScrollView addSubview:viewForTaskScrollView];

viewContentSize = viewContentSizeBase * (countForTaskView);
taskScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(taskView.frame.size.width, viewContentSize);
[taskScrollView setPagingEnabled:YES];
}


- (void) dismissPopover:(NSString *)data
{ /* Dismiss you popover here and process data */ 


 [self.myPopover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
[self setTasksInScreen];

//[myPopover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];


}


// Some method, when you create popover


-(BOOL)popoverControllerShouldDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController{
return YES;
}

-(void)popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController{


}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
[super viewDidUnload];
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
// e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

[super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}



- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft);
}

- (void)deviceOrientationDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification {

[self setTasksInScreen];

}
```

@end

Comment: If you could post code, that'd be helpful.  However, my guess is that your TaskViewController doesn't have a property "projectToolBar" defined in it.  If you have got something of that name defined in your class, ensure that the case matches.

Comment: @twilson I added some code...

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, your TaskViewController doesn't have a projectView (another XIB thing), it does however have a taskView and newTaskView.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Most likely you have a xib file that houses a toolBar that is still connected to a (now nonexistent) outlet named `projectToolBar`.

You removed `IBOutlet UIToolBar *projectToolBar;` from your `TaskViewController.h` file.

---

You should think about using source control management, so you can see what you did. ;-)
[Xcode 4 Guide - Managing Versions of Your Project](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/SCM/SCM.html)

Comment: So I tried this, and it sort of worked. It got rid of one error, but now I have a new one. I updated my post with the new error and code...

Comment: There were two instances of where an object was still connected in the IB but had disappeared in the header file. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

I'm betting you're trying to fill your `TaskViewController` using `setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:` or something like that, and `projectToolBar` isn't a valid `@property` in your view controller's header file.

It could also be what @MatthiasBauch said.

Comment: I think that this might be part of the problem, but I can't find anywhere where I would be setting values or using a dictionary or keys....Where would I look? I updated my post with the new error I'm getting as well as code

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error after adding a few objects to a UITableViewCell on storyboard. Before that, the app was working perfectly.

I was able to resolve this issue by going Xcode > Preferences > Locations > Derived Data, ,opened the directory and deleted the folders with the app's name.

Hope my comment will be helpful for those come here later.